# Lubuntu stuck at boot logo when touchscreen monitor is plugged in

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, touchscreen

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre running Lubuntu and a Dell touchscreen monitor which has a USB for auxilliary USB ports on the monitor and the touchscreen itself. I have connected a mouse and a keyboard to the auxilliary ports.

When trying to boot up the PC with the USB cable plugged in, it will stay frozen on the Lenovo boot logo. The only way to boot it is to unplug the cable, wait for it to go past the boot phase and then plug it back.

The BIOS has the Lubuntu installation as its top priority.

Comment: The release of Lubuntu may be useful; ie. legacy with LXDE or modern with LXQt.   I suspect your issue is with the Ubuntu base more than DEsktop, but the release info is useful to know how modern a kernel etc. too.

Comment: Lubuntu 19.04 x86_64 on kernel version 5.0.0-27-generic with LXQt. I've cheked and this also happens on Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64 on kernel version 5.0.0-13-generic with Gnome.